# Using Google Maps Geocoding API

Tags: ios5, geocoding, cllocation

Basically I need to get info like state, county, zip code with a user's lat/lng coords from a CLLocation object.

Does anyone know if Google has an Objective-C library  for its Geocoding service? Or maybe with iOS 6 maps this will be handled by Apple's API. Running into Google API limits when using query string:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=39.76144296429947,-104.8011589050293&sensor=false

so I am hoping I can use an API key/ Google Wallet account to make these calls freely, via native Objc calls. Basically I need to get info like state, county, zip code with a user's lat/lng coords from a CLLocation object.

Suggestions on where to look for info on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone visiting this answer and not looked hard enough,

[CLGeocoder class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLGeocoder_class/Reference/Reference.html)
 does all of this. You need to show a map with it as part of the usage terms... or you did previously have to - dont quote me on it!!!